# Power problem or fried motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power

I was trying to adjust an antenna on a wireless card and ended up pulling the card loose. Now the computer won't turn on. Did i fry the motherboard?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe/maybe not, but you should provide more information if you want help or some suggestions.

- Is this a laptop or desktop.
- Did you notice or feel any sparks, smoke, etc. when you were working on the motherboard?
- Have you tried reseating power connectors and double checked all connections?
- When you say it won't turn on, to what extent?  Does pressing the power button do anything at all?  i.e. beep codes or error lights of any kind?
- And finally, just cause I've been there - is it plugged in?

Comment: Amen to that - make sure you didn't bump the power cord or accidentally flip the power strip switch! Oh, the number of times I've done that...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unplugging the power cord for a minute. We have a number of computers that will not power up after an abnormal shutdown. Unplugging the power cord then plugging it back in and the computer boots right up.